# Could not load assembly 'Jar_binding Xamarin 4.0

Tags: android, xamarin, youtube-api, xamarin.forms

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Jar_binding, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?   youtube_demo

Answer (score 0):

I think you are Programming in Xamarin using **Visual Studio** !

This is already reported as [**Bug 33748**](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33748)

Try **Cleaning** and **Restarting** your Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio and reopen with a sample.
It can sometimes remove the Bug.

Comment: I build same thing in Xamarin Studio and it run :) but not for Visual Studio does't matter the number of tries i done very baad experience